# Easy way to maximize textbox in web application

Tags: asp.net

We have an existing asp.net application that has alot of textboxes on some screens, it was asked by users that these be bigger or resizeable.  I don't want them to be able to resize them as this could wreck the layout.  Instead I thought it would be best if they had the ability to dbl click in the textbox and be presented with a modal dialog with a larger textbox that they can use and on clicking save puts the text back.

I can write something to do this but would appreciate peoples thoughts, ideas and possibly existing solutions that may do this already I've missed.

Comment: How about using ondblclick="openpopup()" for javascript/jquery, i am supposing you know how to open modal popup.

Comment: Yes I have no issue writing this myself but wanted to see if anyone had a better solution or if possible an existing plugin or solution I could use to save time.